# phpmyadmin открывается у меня в ветке сайта

Tags: ubuntu, apache, phpmyadmin

при url https://mysite.com/phpmyadmin открывается панель phpmyadmin с требованием к логину и паролю. раньше не сталкивался с таким ибо использовал сразу готовые виртуал хостинги которые предоставляли базу данных. вопрос - так и должно быть или этот недочет можно как-то исправить так чтобы phpmyadmin не открывался для обычных юзеров моего сайта

Comment: Если требуется логин и пароль, значит всё закрыто, в чём проблема тогда? Если вы хотите чтобы у обычных юзеров ссылка вообще не открывалась — как тогда отличить конкретно вас от обычных юзеров?

Comment: ну можно банальным подбором паролей войти в базу данных что мне не нужно

Comment: Очевидно, поставьте небанальный неподбираемый пароль

Comment: можно как-то по сессии на сайте определять я ли это или другой юзер

Comment: А как сессия должна отличать конкретно вас от обычных юзеров?

Comment: в сессии юзеры разбиты по группам у обычных юзеров $_SESSION['USER_GROUP'] = 1, у меня как у владельца сайта $_SESSION['USER_GROUP'] = 5

Comment: можно ли как-то реализовать проверку на группу юзера в самом index.php файле phpmyadmin?